# React Native: Logic for rendering item details when FlatList item is tapped

Tags: react-native

Hello React Native Devs ... I am new to RN and stuck at a point in a app I am developing ... In one of the screens of a app I am working on I need to render items as shown in the image below.

[image]

The categories are in the left column and on tapping on one of the categories (e.g. Burgers) will show the items in that category which are shown in the middle column and on tapping on a item (e.g. Beef Burger) in the middle column will show the details for that item which is the right column ... the issue is I cannot figure out how to get items for a category when tapped ... I am using FlatList ... Below is my code if someone wants to inspect.

```
export default class Menu extends Component {

    state = {
        categories: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Burgers',
                items: [
                    {
                        itemId: 1,
                        itemName: 'Beef Burger',
                        itemPrice: 2.89,
                        isAvailable: false,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Extra Cheese',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Extra Spicy',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        itemId: 2,
                        itemName: 'Chicken Burger',
                        itemPrice: 1.89,
                        isAvailable: true,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Extra Cheese',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Extra Spicy',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Pizza',
                items: [
                    {
                        itemId: 1,
                        itemName: 'Pepperoni Pizza',
                        itemPrice: 2.89,
                        isAvailable: false,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Extra Cheese',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Extra Spicy',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        itemId: 2,
                        itemName: 'Cheese Lovers Pizza',
                        itemPrice: 1.89,
                        isAvailable: false,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Extra Cheese',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Extra Spicy',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Beverages',
                items: [
                    {
                        itemId: 1,
                        itemName: 'Coca Cola',
                        itemPrice: 2.89,
                        isAvailable: false,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Chilled',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Normal',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        itemId: 2,
                        itemName: 'Coffee',
                        itemPrice: 1.89,
                        isAvailable: false,
                        addons: [
                            {
                                addonId: 1,
                                addonName: 'Full Cream',
                                addonPrice: 0.99,
                                isAddonAvailable: true
                            },
                            {
                                addonId: 2,
                                addonName: 'Milk',
                                addonPrice: 0.89,
                                isAddonAvailable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        restCategories: [],
        itemListSectionVisible: false,
        itemDetailSectionVisible: false,
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.collectCategories(this.state.categories)
    }

    collectCategories = async (catArr) => {
        cats = []

        for (let catID in catArr) {
            let catInfo = {}

            catInfo['catId'] = catArr[catID]['id'];
            catInfo['catName'] = catArr[catID]['name'];
            catInfo['catItems'] = this.collectCategoryItems(catArr[catID]['items'])

            cats.push(catInfo)
        }
        this.setState({restCategories: cats})
        console.log(this.state.categories)
    }

    collectCategoryItems = (itemArr) => {
        catItems = [];
        for (let itemID in itemArr) {
            let itemInfo = {};

            itemInfo['itemId'] = itemArr[itemID]['itemId'];
            itemInfo['itemName'] = itemArr[itemID]['itemName'];
            itemInfo['itemPrice'] = itemArr[itemID]['itemPrice'];

            catItems.push(itemInfo)
        }

        return catItems;
    }

    renderCategoryListItem = (cat) => {
        return (
            <View style={menuStyles.categoryListItemView}>

                <View style={menuStyles.categoryNameView}>
                    <Text style={menuStyles.categoryNameText}>{cat.catName}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={menuStyles.iconView}>
                    <Icon name='arrow-forward' style={menuStyles.categoryArrow}/>
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }

    renderListItem = (item) => {
        return (
            <View style={menuStyles.itemView}>
                <View style={menuStyles.itemThumbView}>
                    <Image source={itemPlaceHolderThumb} style={menuStyles.itemThumb}/>
                </View>
                <View style={menuStyles.itemNameView}>
                    <Text style={menuStyles.itemName}>{item.itemName}</Text>
                    <Text style={menuStyles.itemPrice}>$&nbsp;{item.itemPrice}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={menuStyles.itemToggleBtnView}>
                    <Switch
                        value={item.isAvailable ? true : false}
                        trackColor={{
                            false: 'red',
                            true: 'lime'
                        }}
                        ios_backgroundColor='red'
                        onValueChange={() => console.log('Changed')}
                        style={menuStyles.itemToggleBtn}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    renderAddonList = (addon) => {
        return (
            <View style={menuStyles.addonListView}>
                <View style={menuStyles.addonNameView}>
                    <Text style={menuStyles.addonNameText}>{addon.addonName}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={menuStyles.addonPriceView}>
                    <Text style={menuStyles.addonPriceText}>+ $ {addon.addonPrice}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={menuStyles.addonToggleBtnView}>
                    <Switch
                        value={addon.isAddonAvailable ? true : false}
                        trackColor={{
                            false: 'red',
                            true: 'lime'
                        }}
                        ios_backgroundColor='red'
                        onValueChange={() => console.log('Changed')}
                        style={menuStyles.itemToggleBtn}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    showItemListSection = (catIndex) => {
        this.setState({
            itemListSectionVisible: true,
        })
        console.log('index ', catIndex)
    }

    showItemDetailSection = () => {
        this.setState({itemDetailSectionVisible: true})
    }

    render() {
        const {itemListSectionVisible, itemDetailSectionVisible} = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <CustomHeader drawerAction={this.props.navigation.openDrawer.bind(this)}/>
                <View style={menuStyles.container}>
                    <View style={menuStyles.categorySection}>
                        <View style={menuStyles.headingView}>
                            <Text style={menuStyles.headingText}>{'Menu'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={menuStyles.categoryListView}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.restCategories}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.catId.toString()}
                                renderItem={({item, index}) => <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.showItemListSection(item.catId)}>{this.renderCategoryListItem(item)}</TouchableOpacity>}
                                ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Hr/>}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={menuStyles.itemsSection}>
                        <View style={menuStyles.headingView}>
                            <Text style={menuStyles.headingText}>Items</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View style={menuStyles.itemListView}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.categories[0].items}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.itemId.toString()}
                                renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.showItemDetailSection()}>{this.renderListItem(item)}</TouchableOpacity>}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    <View style={menuStyles.itemDetailSection}>
                        <View style={menuStyles.itemDetailImageView}>

                            <Image source={itemPlaceholderImg} style={menuStyles.itemDetailImage}/>

                        </View>
                        <View style={menuStyles.itemDetailNameView}>
                            <Text style={menuStyles.itemDetailNameText}>{'Beef Burger'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                            <Text style={menuStyles.itemDetailDescText}>Duotones are simply the combining of two colors
                                on an image, usually using very bright or contrasting colors. They require a bit of
                                design work but it is most definitely worth it.</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={menuStyles.itemDetailAddonsView}>
                            <View style={menuStyles.addonHeadingView}>
                                <Text style={menuStyles.addonHeadingText}>Addons</Text>
                            </View>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.categories[0].items[0].addons}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.addonId.toString()}
                                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderAddonList(item)}
                                ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Hr/>}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. 
 TIA

Comment: What about adding a snack demo? It will be easy to assist you

Comment: @RaajNadar ... I believe snack demo will work for projects created using CRNA

Comment: No snack is for expo based projects

Comment: @RaajNadar ... I thought so ... but my project is a regular react native project created using react-native init

Answer (score 0):

As you described that you want all the things on one screen, for that, you can do one thing you have to make the multiple flat screens and pass extra data in the flat screen of the this.state so that you can use state variable in the flat list render function by putting conditions you can show and hide the particular flat list and as per the category you can pass the data in the flat list.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I create three different components (e.g. Categories, Items and ItemDetails) with FlatList and pass props to those components ? Right ? ...

Comment: Yes you can do that and by conditions show and hide those list

Answer (score 0):

After struggling and searching on the internet for a few days I found the best solution for my situation ... So i am sharing for those who could be in the same scenario as mine ... The scenario was to load the Items in the 2nd colum and Item Details in the 3rd column when one of the Categories is tapped in the first column ... I tried handling this using component states but it wasn't working for my scenario so I ended up using Redux and after adding some logic to the code i was able to get the desired functionality.